# Can't access localhost on other devices using php artisan serve

Tags: laravel, server, xampp, localhost

recently I was trying to access my laravel web app on the same wifi using another device and it works well(I copied the ipv4 into the --host). However, when I tried it on a different wifi, it doesn't work at all despite following the same steps and using the correct ipv4. May I ask why is that so and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Run this on visual code or CMD, **you must be in laravel directory**,

```
php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0
```

then just go to cmd and type the following:

```
ipconfig | findstr IPv4
```

Copy the IPV4 Address *Your device IP*, and then just simply paste it on your browser with the 8000 port, it should be like this example. (`192.168.100.77:8000`)

**Enjoy Developing!**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access it from another device you should enable it like so :

```
php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0
```

it will allow any device in your network to access it,

and it will work with wifi and with ethernet

If you set your wifi ipv4 in the host but at the same time your are connected with ethernet it won't work

Comment: I tried doing it this way but it seems that even my hosting computer can't reach the 0.0.0.0:8000 website

Comment: Well the hosting computer use localhost:8000 and the other computer use x.x.x.x:8000 where x.x.x.x is the ip address of the hosting computer